# Installing vscode on Almalinux 9 - getting error loading shared lib

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, shared-libraries, almalinux

I just got a Almalinux 9 server and want to use vscode for e.g python coding. The server is not connected to Internet so I have downloaded the rpm package manually.
Installated it as:
sudo dnf --nogpgcheck localinstall code-1.77.3-1681292829.el7.x86_64.rpm

Looked well but when running the vscode it ends up with following error message:
**/usr/share/code/bin/../code: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Looked for a solution and one was to add rows in the file product.json for extensionAllowed
(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/linux).
However, it did not work for me. Same error message.

Appreciate if knowledge about a solution how to get vscode working on AlmaLinux 9 could be shared

Comment: in my Snap installation, there's a `./usr/share/code/libffmpeg.so` under `/snap/code/current`. Do you have something like that under wherever your VS Code is installed?

Comment: Hi,
Yes, I can see the file /usr/share/code/libffmpeg.so

I did expect that rpm package was complete - and to add, I am new to use AlmaLinux so I do not know if there are other dependencies.

Comment: I updated the path environment variable as:
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/share/code/:/usr/share/:/usr/bin/lib/:/usr/bin/include/:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/include/                      ......But same result (did export it and thereafter ran sudo ldconfig)